# can flockfile function be used for process

Tags: c, multithreading, process

Hello every one I want to ask a question about flockfile function I was reading the description and came to know that it is used in threads. but I am doing forking which means that there will be different process not threads can I use flockfile with different process does it make any difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The `flockfile` function doesn't lock a file but the `FILE` data structure that a process uses to access a file. So this is about the representation in address space that a process has of the file, not necessarily about the file itself.

Even in a process if you have different `FILE`s open on the same file, you can write simultaneously to that file, even if you have locked each of the `FILE`s by means of `flockfile`.

For locking on the file itself have a look into `flock` and `lockf` but beware that the rules of their effects for access files through different threads of the same process are complicated.

Answer (score 1):

These functions can only be used within one process.

From the [POSIX docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/flockfile.html):

> In summary, threads sharing stdio streams with other threads can use flockfile() and funlockfile() to cause sequences of I/O performed by a single thread to be kept bundled.

All the rest of that page talks about mutual exclusion between threads. Different processes will have different input/output buffers for file streams, this locking wouldn't really make sense/be effective.